# retrieve item from a json file c#

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "_id": "underscore",
    "_rev": "136-824a0ef7436f808755f0712c3acc825f",
    "name": "underscore",
    "description": "JavaScript's functional programming helper library.",
    "dist-tags": {},
    "versions": {
        "1.0.3": {
            "name": "xxx",
            "description": "xxx"
        },
        "1.0.4": {},
        "1.1.0": {}
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve the latest version(1.1.0) from the json file. However, it always gives out me errors of "can not deserialize json object into type RootObject

Here is my class

```
public class versions
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<versions> vs { get; set; }
}
```

And here is where I used it

```
RootObject[] dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);
```

Any idea. Many thankx

### **Update:**

I have updated the JSON file format, but some problem..

Comment: what are the problems that you have after the update?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is, that in JSON you have to quote all "field"/attribute names. (Thats a difference from standard Javascript-Notation, where you can have unquoted attributes).

So, your file should be like:

```
{
  "_id" : "underscore",
  "versions": {
    "1.0.3" : {
       "name": "xxx",
       "description": "xxx"
    }
}
```

Note that `{1.0.3: { name: "xxx" } }` wouldn't be valid JavaScript either since '1.0.3' is an invalid identifier in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your json in question. Now for your real question

> I would like to retrieve the latest version(1.1.0) from the json file. However, it always gives out me errors of "can not deserialize json object into type RootObject

You have property names like `1.0.3` that are unknown at compile time. So you can not deserialize them to a concrete class. You should handle them dynamically.

Try this:

```
var versions = JObject.Parse(json)["versions"]
               .Children()
               .Cast<JProperty>()
               .ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => c.Value.ToObject<versions>());
```

Comment: Erorrs: can not inferred from the usage.. To dictionary and toObject is  wrong, i assume

Comment: @user1851359 I tested it before posting. No errors. Have you included `System.Linq` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JSON in your updated answer:

```
{
  "_id" : "underscore",
  "versions": {
    "1.0.3" : {
       "name": "xxx",
       "description": "xxx"
    },
   "1.0.4" : {
       "name": "xxx",
       "description": "xxx"
    }
}
```

This is still Invalid JSON - you have 4 opening { and only 3 closing }

you should use http://jsonlint.com/ - to validate your JSON and ensure it is Valid